# Razor View Does Not Display Records

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I created an ASP.NET Core MVC project in VS 2022. I used EF power tool to create `DbContext` and model classes, added connection string route map in `program.cs`.

But my view is blank and does not display any records from controller. Actually, the `HomeController` never gets hit when debugging. I have no idea where the problem is and what code I am missing.

**Program.cs**:

```
using Courses.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//add connection string
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
{
    
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
//map route
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

**HomeController**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Courses.Models;

namespace Courses.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DbContext _db;

        // GET: HomeController
        public HomeController(DbContext context)
        {
            _db = context;
        }
    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var subjectList = _db.subjectTable.OrderBy(a => a.Subject).ToList();
            return View(subjectList);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. When I created the project, it generates a Pages folder with pages underneath it. My HomeController gets hit after I removed the Pages folder.